# game menu in another class or in game class?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

we are about to finish our app for the iphone.

all the game is in one class `helloWorldLayer.mm` . using cocos2d.

Now i need to add the game menu.

2 ways.

1. adding it in the same class on the init method and just call it from there as a sprite with buttons .
2. make another class to be the gameMenu class and call this class from the delegate with:

> ```
> [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: [gameMenu scene]];
> ```

then from the game menu to load the game scene with :

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene: [HelloWorldLayer scene]];
```

is that method ok ?  do i have to add something else? release something?
does memory is better with the **first** or the **second** ?

thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little game menu screen scene should be better - mostly for the sake of organization. Having your menu in a separate scene or in the game class itself shouldn't make much difference, but I would still prefer to have it separately. You could also do some fancy scene transition effect.

Comment: thanks a lot. i have 1 small issue, . Do i have to release all the sprites and other stuff when going from game scene to menu?  for example i have a timer that repeats in the game scene. when going from game to menu, whats happen to that timer? do i have to invalidate it first ? and remove the sprites and backgrounds before? or does cocos2d release them all by it self ?

Comment: If you didn't alloc/retain anything by your own, don't worry about it (cocos2d will release its own stuff). If you used *retain* or *alloc* when creating an object, you should use *release* at some point. But if you didn't use them, don't release. Also, as for the timer thing, if you mean you got a NSTimer thing, I am not sure. For all timer-related things, you should use instead cocos2d's scheduler. Basically go to your scene and do something like *[self schedule:@selector(myScheduledMethod) interval:0.5];*

Comment: thanks a lot! so if i use that selector instead of timers, i dont have to release it or worry about it anymore ? is it better then timer?

Comment: Yes, it is by far better than NSTimer for your cocos2d games. In fact, it is documented in the "best practices" page for cocos2d: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:best_practices#timers

And yes, you don't have to "release" or do anything at the end with your scheduler. Cocos2d takes care of that part.